# Extracting personal ID of the signee from a digital signature

Tags: pdf, digital-signature

I need to validate the identity of the person who digitally signed a given PDF file, with a P7M (CAdES) digital signature.

When I open the document usign a digital signature tool (Dike is a popular software for doing that, in Italy), the signature validation function of the tool shows the personal ID of the person who signed (which in Italy is called "Codice fiscale", a sort of SSN), so that information must be somewhere in the signed file.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a software library that, given the PDF.P7M file, returns be such "Codice fiscale". Can someone please help (mainly italian developers, I guess). Thanks!.

Comment: If you shared an example file, non-Italian developers could help, too. Furthermore, which programming language are you using?

Comment: You may need to extract the principal from the certificate which contains the X.500 Distinguished Name (DN). This distinguished name contains several fields such as the Common Name. I've seen at least one description of an Italian certificate where the TIN is the serial number (which would not be according to best practices, of course).